# Android IPC Remote service call display Error

Tags: android, ipc, aidl, inter-process-communicat

I want to make one demo application regarding the IPC communication .(Communication between Service).
I am using `AIDL`  for that .

I found most of tutorial the `RemoteService` and Client are in same package .

I actually do it separately ,While passing the object I am using `Parcelable`Method and facing Error ...

**It said like The `RemoteService Signature`  unable to find your class..**
I displayed my Logcat Below also :
If you have any solution please guide me ...or any interdependent server client service tutorials or documents..

***LOGCAT:***

```
06-20 14:47:53.973: W/dalvikvm(4465): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/sam/zserver/IQRemoteService;)
06-20 14:47:54.003: I/dalvikvm(4465): Could not find method com.sam.zserver.IQRemoteService.getCounter, referenced from method com.quip.zclient.ZIPCClientActivity.invokeService
06-20 14:47:54.003: W/dalvikvm(4465): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 53: Lcom/sam/zserver/IQRemoteService;.getCounter ()I
06-20 14:47:54.023: D/dalvikvm(4465): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0011
06-20 14:47:54.023: D/dalvikvm(4465): VFY: dead code 0x0014-0054 in Lcom/quip/zclient/ZIPCClientActivity;.invokeService ()V
06-20 14:47:54.273: I/ActivityManager(61): Displayed com.quip.zclient/.ZIPCClientActivity: +588ms
06-20 14:47:59.363: D/dalvikvm(226): GC_EXPLICIT freed 10K, 55% free 2595K/5703K, external 716K/1038K, paused 53ms
06-20 14:48:05.073: D/dalvikvm(245): GC_EXPLICIT freed 6K, 54% free 2543K/5511K, external 716K/1038K, paused 36ms
06-20 14:48:10.122: D/dalvikvm(306): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4K, 54% free 2537K/5511K, external 716K/1038K, paused 71ms
06-20 14:48:15.113: D/dalvikvm(4129): GC_EXPLICIT freed 14K, 53% free 2579K/5379K, external 716K/1038K, paused 49ms
```

Thanks;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know exactly but it seems that you did not put aidl in your client application. You should put aidl in Service and in the Client application.